# Missing Return in closure - Swift Trying to hide/show in UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, xcode, show-hide, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to hide an item when you toggle over to one and reveal it when toggled back, but it's telling me that I'm 'Missing return in closure expected to return UISegmentedControl'. Does that mean I have to make a workaround? If so, how would I go about doing that? this is the first application I've made without the storyboard and instead I'm programming the UI.

[Issue Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaoHV.png)

```
lazy var loginRegisterSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1

    switch sc.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0: self.nameTextField.isHidden = true
    case 1: self.nameTextField.isHidden = false
    default:
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
       return sc
    }

}()
```

Comment: Note that in your code `sc.selectedSegmentIndex` is *always* `1`, so even if you fix the "missing return" issue, `case 0:` and `default:` would never be executed. You may need to rethink your logic.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

In the initialisation of your `lazy var loginRegisterSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl` you need to make sure to put `return sc` at the end of the initialiser.

Comment: So above the switch?

Comment: @DarinWilson, if you put it **above** switch, switch will be never executed. Any other options come to mind?

Comment: @YordiLorenzo I have it below the switch and tried to put it between the } and }() still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to put it completely below the switch statement, not in the default case. If you updated please upload your code to help you further.